# Time execution paradox

Tags: c++, boost, time

I'm benchmarking the Dijkstra's Algorithm using the Boost Graph Library and I realize that some function in my code has an execution time that is (much) greater that the sum of the execution times of the successive parts I have splitted it up:

```
Part 1: 0.521417                                                                                                                                                
Part 2: 0.000022                                                                                                                                                
Part 3: 0.543387
Whole: 2.283262
```

Below is the code. The function to consider is the `test_dijkstra` function. The dataset file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AbbAa9-yDyuJ3btlFF_l982TXJUKhRG6/view?usp=sharing) (60 MB).

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <boost/config.hpp>

#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using namespace std::chrono;

typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, undirectedS,
        no_property, property < edge_weight_t, int > > graph_t;
typedef graph_traits < graph_t >::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef pair<int, int> Edge;

typedef struct Data
{
    int n, m;
    int src;
    vector<Edge> edges;
    vector<int> weights;
} Data;


void print_elapsed_time(steady_clock::time_point start, steady_clock::time_point end)
{
    double elapsedSeconds = ((end - start).count()) * steady_clock::period::num / static_cast<double>(steady_clock::period::den);
    printf("%lf\n", elapsedSeconds);
}


auto capture()
{
    FILE *dataset=fopen("test_6000.in", "r");
    auto pdata=make_unique<Data>();
    int m, n, src;

    fscanf(dataset,"%d %d %d", &n, &m, &src);

    pdata->n=n;
    pdata->m=m;
    pdata->src=src;


    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        int a, b, w;

        fscanf(dataset,"%d %d %d", &a, &b, &w);
        (pdata->edges).push_back(make_pair(a, b));
        (pdata->weights).push_back(w);
    }

    return pdata;
}


void test_dijkstra(Edge *edge_array, int *weights, int n, int m, int src)
{

    auto start1 = steady_clock::now();
    graph_t g(edge_array, edge_array + m, weights, n);
    auto end1 = steady_clock::now();
    printf("Part 1: ");
    print_elapsed_time(start1, end1);

    auto start2 = steady_clock::now();
    vector<vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));
    vector<int> d(num_vertices(g));
    vertex_descriptor s = vertex(src, g);
    auto end2 = steady_clock::now();
    printf("Part 2: ");
    print_elapsed_time(start2, end2);

    auto start3 = steady_clock::now();
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, s, predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]));
    auto end3 = steady_clock::now();
    printf("Part 3: ");
    print_elapsed_time(start3, end3);
}

int main (void)
{
    auto pdata=capture();
    auto data=*pdata;
    auto edges=data.edges;
    auto weights=data.weights;
    auto pedges=&edges[0];
    auto pweights=&weights[0];

    int n, m, src;

    n=data.n;
    m=data.m;
    src=data.src;

    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    test_dijkstra(pedges, pweights, n, m, src);
    auto end = steady_clock::now();

    printf("Whole: ");
    print_elapsed_time(start, end);

    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain this "paradox"?

Comment: Use a profiler.

Comment: This test is not authoritative, because in your function `test_dijkstra` you have many local variables which are destroyed - and of course this work also takes some time, but you don't measure this.

Comment: output is slow. ultra slow. and in your "whole" measurement you include all the prints from the inner function. store them somewhere and print all timings later on

Comment: @phön Sorry, but a `printf` is not going to take half a second in all but the most pathological cases (which "print 1 double" does certainly not fall under).

Comment: You could (_for debugging only_) create global variables for time points that you take right before the function call and right after entering the function call, as well as right before the end of the function call and right after it returns. I agree with @rafix07 that destruction of large objects with automatic storage duration (i.e. `g`, maybe `p` and `d`) at the end of the function's scope is the likely explanation here, which you should see in the latter pair of time points I suggested.

Comment: @rafix07@Max Langhof This is very interesting. If I remove part 2 and part 3 from the test function the delta time remains very high this means that the graph object do a lot of cleanup